# Frechet derivative chain rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to prove that,

> Fix $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m, V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f =
>  (f_1,\cdots,f_n):U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(U)\subset V$ and each
>   coordinate function $f_k:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at the
>   point $a\in U$. Let $g:V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function
>   at the point $b=f(a)$. Then, the composite $g\circ f:U\to\mathbb{R}$
>   is differentiable in $a$ and its partial derivatives are given by:
>
> $$\frac{\partial(g\circ f)}{\partial x_i}(a) =
>  \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_k}(b)\cdot \frac{\partial
>  f_k}{\partial x_i}(a)$$

Here's the demonstration in my book:

Let $U_0$ be the set of vectors $v = (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $a+v\in U$. For $v\in U_0$ and $k=1,\cdots,n$ we have:

$$f_k(a+v) = f_k(a)+\sum_{i=1}\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i}\cdot \alpha_i + p_k\cdot |v|$$

where each $p_k = p_k(v)$ is a function defined in $U_0$, continuous in point $0$, which annihilates when $v=0$

(We'll consider $\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_k}$ to be in the points $a$ and $b$ respectively).

Consider the application $w = (\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n):U_0\to\mathbb{R}^n$, continuous in $0$ such that the coordinate functions are defined by:

$$\beta_k(v) = \sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i}\cdot \alpha_i + p_k\cdot |v|$$

Adopting, for example, the norm of the sum, we have $|\alpha_i|/|v|\le 1$ if $v\neq 0$, therefore each $|\beta_k|/|v|$, and therefore the function $|w|/|v|$, is bounded in a neighborhood of $v=0$. **Writing $gf$ instead of $g\circ f$, we can say that by the formula for $f_k(a+v)$ given before, that, from differentiability of $g$ in $b=f(a)$ and that for al v\in U_0$, we have:**

$$gf(a+v) = g(b+w) = g(b) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_k}\cdot \beta_k + \sigma\cdot |w|$$

where $\sigma = \sigma(v)$ is a continuous real function in $0$, which anihilates in $v=0$.

Then it just concludes that this is the proof

What is that **'writing $gf$ instead of $g\circ f$'** thing?

Comment: It means that the author shall write thereinafter $gf$ instead of $g \circ f$

Comment: @WillM. wait, what? Because how did $gf(a+v)$ turned into $g(b+w)$?

Comment: Since $f(a+v)=f(a)+...$

Comment: @WillM. I imagined this, but why?

Comment: I don't know what book are you reading but it seems that it misses the gist of derivative: $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there exists a linear continuous function $T$ such that the difference $f(a+h)-f(a)$ is approximately $Th$ with an error $o(\|h\|).$

Comment: So, $f(a+h)=f(a)+Th+o(\|h\|)$

Comment: @WillM. but where did this error go? If you could write more precisely, I'd open a bounty and reward you. Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted? Are there still open questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I shall give a demonstration of the chain rule in a bit more general context.

**Definition.** A function $f,$ defined on an open subset of a *normed* vector space $\mathrm{V}$ and with values in another normed space $\mathrm{W}$, is differentiable at the point $a$ (in its domain) if there exists a *continuous* linear function $\mathrm{T}:\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ such that $f(a + h) = f(a) + \mathrm{T}h + o(\|h\|)$ as $h \to 0,$ where, as it is standard, "$u = o(v(x))$ as $x \to x_0$" (here $u$ is a $\mathrm{W}$-valued function and $v$ is a nonnegative function) means $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ v(x) \neq 0}}\dfrac{\|u(x)\|}{v(x)} = 0.$

**Corollary 1.** If $f$ is differentiable at $a,$ its derivate is unique. (If $\mathrm{T}$ and $\mathrm{L}$ satisfy the defining property of being differentiable, one gets $(\mathrm{T} - \mathrm{L})h = o(h)$ which implies at once $\|\mathrm{T} - \mathrm{L}\| = 0$ or $\mathrm{T} = \mathrm{L}$). Whence, one denotes by $f'(a)$ the derivative of $f$ at $a$ (so, $f'(a):h \mapsto f'(a) \cdot h$ is a continuous linear function).

**Corollary 2.** The derivative of the restriction of linear continuous function in any interior point of its domain, is the linear function.

**Remarks.**

(1) The *derivative* need not scalars in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C,$ so most proofs
    regarding only differentiation are valid simultaneosly in the
    complexes or in the reals.

(2) Since the derivative is unique, its
    definition basically says that a function being differentiable at
    one point $a$ is the same as saying that "in the small
    neighbourhoods of $a,$ the increments of $f$ behave as a linear
    component plus an error that is infinitesimal in comparison with the
    linear part." Such approximation is *unique.*

(3) Therefore, one can
    bet that the best unique *linear approximation* of a composition is
    the composition of the best uniques *linear approximations* of the components; this is the "chain rule", which, by the way, loses all its trace of meaning when one forces (as your book does) an arbitrary expansion of some basis.

**Chain rule.** Assume $\mathrm{U}, \mathrm{V}$ and $\mathrm{W}$ are three normed spaces; let $\mathrm{E}$ be an open subset of $\mathrm{U}$ and $\mathrm{F}$ another such for $\mathrm{V}.$ Suppose $f:\mathrm{E} \to \mathrm{V}$ and $g:\mathrm{F} \to \mathrm{W}$ are differentiable at $a \in \mathrm{E}$ and $b = f(a) \in \mathrm{F},$ respectively. Then, $g \circ f,$ which is defined on some neighbourhood of $a,$ is differentiable at $a$ and its derivative is $(g \circ f)'(a) = g'(f(a)) \circ f'(a).$

*Proof.* In some small neighbourhood $\mathrm{B}_1$ of $a,$ the following expansion follows from definition $$f(a + h) = f(a) + f'(a) \cdot h + o_f(\|h\|) = b + f'(a) \cdot h + o_f(\|h\|).$$ Similarly, in some small neighbourhood $\mathrm{C}_1$ of $b,$ $$g(b + k) = g(b) + g'(b) \cdot k + o_g(\|k\|).$$ Since $\|f'(a) \cdot h + o_f(\|h\|)\| \leq \left(\|f'(a)\| + \left\|\dfrac{o_f(\|h\|)}{\|h\|}\right\|\right) \|h\|,$ one can restrict $h \in \mathrm{B}_2 \subset \mathrm{B}_1$ such that $k = f'(a) \cdot h + o_f(\|h\|)$ has norm $\leq (\|f'(a)\| + 1) \|h\|.$ If necessary, restrict further $h \in \mathrm{B}_3 \subset \mathrm{B}_2$ such that $b + k \in \mathrm{C}_1,$ where $k$ is as before. Therefore, for $h \in \mathrm{B}_3,$
$$\begin{array}
((g \circ f)(a + h) &= g(b + k) = g(b) + g'(b) \cdot k + o_g(\|k\|) \\
&= g(b) + g'(b) \cdot (f'(a) \cdot h + o_f(\|h\|)) + o_g(\|k\|) \\
&= g(b) + g'(f(a)) f'(a) \cdot h + g'(b) \cdot o_f(\|h\|) + o_g(\|k\|) \\
&= g(b) + g'(f(a)) f'(a) \cdot h + \psi(h),
\end{array}$$
where $\psi(h) = g'(b) \cdot o_f(\|h\|) + o_g(\|k\|)$ is defined for $h \in \mathrm{B}_3$ and needs to be shown that, when divided by $\|h\|,$ the quotient tends to zero. This is easy, because $\|k\| \leq (\|f'(a)\| + 1)\|h\|,$ so $\psi(h)$ is the sum of two $o(\|h\|)$ functions, making this of $\psi$ a $o(\|h\|)$ function too. The proof is terminated. CQFD

**Corollary.** If $f$ is defined in some open subset of $\Bbb R^p$ with values in $\Bbb R^q$, then, the $q \times p$ matrix that represents $f'(x)$ in the canonical basis is $\left( \dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \right)_{\substack{i = 1, \ldots, p\\j = 1, \ldots, q}}.$ (Since the limit is coordinatewise, it suffices to consider the case $q = 1;$ for this case consider the canonical injection $\eta_j:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^p$ and the canonical projection $\pi_i:\Bbb R^p \to \Bbb R,$ then notice that that (1) these functions are linear and continuous, hence differentiable everywhere with them being their own derivate and (2) the identity of $\Bbb R^d$ can be written as $id = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^p \eta_k \circ \pi_k$ and apply the chain rule to $f = id \circ f$).